# How can I replace the first item in a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I have a dynamic string and I would like to remove the first attribute of an item it could find. I have the following code:

```
mystring = '''
item 1
item 2
*item 3
item 4
*item 5
'''
mystring = mystring.replace('*', '')
print((mystring))
```

This returns:

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
item 5
```

But I want it to only replace the first instance of `*` which in this case is `*item 3`. It should return:

```
item 1
item 2
item 4
*item 5
```

I basically want it to delete the first line that starts with `*` How can I go about doing this? Do I need to use regex?

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 in args -

```
mystring = mystring.replace('*', '',1)
print((mystring))
```

Comment: But won't this just remove the ```*```? How can I make it remove the entire line if it starts with ```*```

Comment: use startswith function in if condition and if control goes inside the if condition replace the char and break, or use ^ at the start of regex.